Table Contents Not Centered
Consider the following MWE:
% lualatex test.tex

\DocumentMetadata{}

\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
    Column~A & Column~B \\
  \hline
    11       & 12       \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


As can (hopefully) be seen in the screendump, the centents isn't centered within each row; it is too close to the top.
I've had this problem for as long as I can remember but I've always forgotten to ask for a solution, so here we go: How do I vertically center the centents of each row?
P.S. I know that I should probably use booktabs when typesetting tables, and often I do. :-)
Update
It seems that \extrarowheight is my 'rescuer' here. However, others must have the same problem so I'm wondering of there is a more general fix to it?

You're misled by the missing descenders.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}% for the second set
\usepackage{booktabs}% for the third set

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
    Column A & Column B \\
  \hline
    11       & 12       \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
    Colymn A & Copumn B \\
  \hline
    11       & 12       \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
    Column A & Column B \\
  \hline
    11       & 12       \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{cc}
  \hline
    Colymn A & Copumn B \\
  \hline
    11       & 12       \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\setlength{\extrarowheight}{0pt}

\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
    Column A & Column B \\
\midrule
    11       & 12       \\
    11       & 12       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}\qquad
\begin{tabular}{cc}
\toprule
    Colymn A & Copumn B \\
\midrule
    11       & 12       \\
    11       & 12       \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{document}


The table on the right shows why there seems to be more space at the bottom than at the top.
Look now at the second set: the table on the right is unbalanced.
In the third set no unbalancing is noticed in either table.

I see your point with the descenders in the text column, egreg, but I still find it unnatural  that 11 and 12 are not centered in the top tables in your example since numbers never have descenders.

I think this might be what you want:
\usepackage{array}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{1pt}



After a bit of thought, I have a feeling that this will only work if each row has (approximately) the same height. I could easily be wrong, but I'm not at a computer with a TeX distribution at the moment, so I can't test my hypothesis.

Good idea. I'd actually go for \setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}. :-)

@Mico Does the extra 2pt center the contents no matter the height of each row? (I'm still not near a TeX distribution so testing isn't possible at the moment, unfortunately.)

@SvendTveskæg - Short answer: no. Slightly longer answer: horizontal or vertical centering is as much an aesthetic as a geometric issue. For the example at hand, 2pt (to my eyes) produces a more pleasing-looking result than 1pt does, as my eye seems to value or appreciate the negative space above the words/numerals more than it does the negative space below the words/numerals. A really long answer could go on for hours and hours...
